# How to handle native execption 0xc0000005 (Access violation) in vb.net windows CE(.net CF 2.0) application

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am having a 0xc0000005 ACCESS VIOLATION execption in winCE vb.net application.

**Details**

Visual Studio 2005,.net Framework 2.0 (Compact Framework), Windows CE 6.0, Third party printing dll

**Background**

I click on the Ok button of the form, it creates a string for printing label, then a Text file is created on the device. after the Text file is created a third party dll call is send to initialize the bluetooth connection with the printer and then print the label on the portable printer.

**Issue**

After clicking on the Ok button i get the error message that application has to be killed due to some fatal error and then another message shows the native execption code and application shutsdown.

**Images**

[Application has to be killed due to some fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSJ5j.png)

[Error execption code : 0xc0000005 Execption Address: 0x4006183c Writing: 0x42fb9000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCgTk.png)

Can any help me out about how to handle this error in vb.net because it is not catched in the try...catch block.

*Update:*

**Code**

below code is where i create the text file on the device which has the printing string.

```
Dim objEncodingConvertor As New UnicodeEncoding
Dim objTest As System.Text.Encoding
Dim btBytesToWrite() As Byte
objTest = objEncodingConvertor.GetEncoding(932)

objFileHandler = New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create)
btBytesToWrite = objTest.GetBytes(strStringData)
objFileHandler.Write(btBytesToWrite, 0, btBytesToWrite.Length)
objFileHandler.Close()
```

below is the code for initializing the bluetooth printer using third party dll.

```
<DllImport("PTDRV.dll")> _
Public Shared Function Pt_Init_Bluetooth(ByVal PrinterBTAddress As String, ByVal PrinterLevel As Integer, ByVal PrinterPINCode As String, ByVal PrinterCRCCode As Integer, ByVal PrinterTimeOut As Integer, ByVal PrinterRetry As Integer, ByVal DebugMode As Integer) As Int32
End Function

intResult = Pt_Init_Bluetooth(PrinterMacAddress, 0, "9999999999999999", 0, 5000, 5, 0)
```

Comment: Impossible to say on this information, but Access Violation exceptions should not occur in .NET, obviously, being a managed environment. This means that the error is likely occurring at the driver level. I would take a close look at the way you are calling the third party dll.

Comment: Kindly post the code here which you have tried

Comment: -please find the related code

Comment: -just for information this error occurs sometimes but as the application gets shutdown i need to handle it.